# JPA Glassfish Database Update Issue

Tags: jpa, persistence, glassfish, java-ee-6

I have an application deployed on Glassfish v3.0.1 which reads events from a table in my database. Once ready it marks them as processed. I am getting a strange error I can't explain when trying to call the method which does the update.

```
@Override
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void markEventAsProcessed(Long eventId) {
    try {
       AtlasEventQueueUpdateAsProcessedQuery setEventAsProcessed = new  AtlasEventQueueUpdateAsProcessedQuery(entityManager, eventId);
       int updateCount = setEventAsProcessed.execute();
       logger.debug("Mark Event [" + eventId + "] processed");
       return updateCount;
    } catch (QueryException ex) {
        logger.error("Event [" + eventId + "has not been marked as processed", ex);
    }
}
```

When this is called in my application I am getting the following exception (Full trace at the bottom of the post):

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.AccessLocalException: Client not authorized for this invocation.
```

Does anyone know what might cause this error I have loked on the Web but didn't find anything useful.

```
2010-08-27 09:44:37,380 ERROR [Ejb-Timer-Thread-1  :EventProvider       ] Unhandled exception in event processing - javax.ejb.EJBAccessException
javax.ejb.EJBAccessException
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.mapLocal3xException(BaseContainer.java:2262)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2053)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1955)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:198)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:84)
        at $Proxy190.markEventAsProcessed(Unknown Source)
        at com.company.atlas.eventprocessor.provider.EventProvider.processNewEvents(EventProvider.java:170)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1056)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1128)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5292)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:615)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:567)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:157)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundTimeout(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:858)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:367)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5264)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5252)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.callEJBTimeout(BaseContainer.java:3965)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.deliverTimeout(EJBTimerService.java:1667)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.access$100(EJBTimerService.java:98)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService$TaskExpiredWork.run(EJBTimerService.java:2485)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: javax.ejb.AccessLocalException: Client not authorized for this invocation.
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1850)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:188)
        ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> I've deleted the directory `domains/domainx/generated/policy/<appname>/`
>   and completly redeployed (not just restarted) the app.. its working now as expected.

The GlassFish documentation has an entry for this error:

> ### [`javax.ejb.AccessLocalException:` Client Not Authorized Error](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4339/abgjw?l=En&a=view)
>
> #### Description
>
> Role-mapping information is available
>   in Sun-specific XML (for example,
>   `sun-ejb-jar.xml`), and authentication
>   is okay, but the following error
>   message is displayed:
>
> ```
> [...INFO|sun-appserver-pe8.0|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb|...|
> javax.ejb.AccessLocalException: Client not authorized for this invocation.
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:...
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(...)
> ```
>
> #### Solution
>
> Check whether the EJB module (`.jar`)
>   or web module (`.war`) is packaged in
>   an application (`.ear`) and does not
>   have role-mapping information in
>   application level, Sun-specific,
>   `sun-application.xml`. For any
>   application (`.ear`), security
>   role-mapping information must be
>   specified in `sun-application.xml`. It
>   is acceptable to have both
>   module-level XML and application-level
>   XML.

I don't know if it makes sense in your context.

If it doesn't, maybe have a look at the following thread [Persisting Entity: javax.ejb.AccessLocalException: Client not authorized for this invocation](http://old.nabble.com/Persisting-Entity:-javax.ejb.AccessLocalException:-Client-not--authorized-for-this-invocation.-td26848696.html). One of the poster suggested to *set the logging level of the SECURITY Logger to FINE [so that] the Glassfish Policy subsystem will log a detailed message describing the nature of the failed permission check*. This might help. And I can't tell you if you're facing the same problem but the OP solved his issue by cleaning the generated policy files:

Comment: I delete content of domain folders `generated`, `eclipseApps`, `osgi-cache\felix` to make sure all necessary files get regenerated.

Comment: Note that this error will present if there are two many <role-name> tags within a single <security-role-mapping> declaration in your descriptor - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423718/why-would-glassfish-generate-an-incomplete-granted-policy-file/17425530#17425530

Comment: This did work for me. It also works, at least with me, restarting glassfish (version 4) and/or restarting Netbeans.

Comment: Payara team focused on problems somehow connected with this problem: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/198

Comment: @Pascal Thivent : Dude you basically saved my life and a big company :-) ! Many thanks! Live long and prosper!!

Answer (score 5):

This exception can also occur, if you try to copy and paste EJB session beans with new methods, as patch files for fixing bugs or incorporating new features. Restarting the server or disabling & enabling the enterprise app will not help, as the EJB Session beans or entities have to be repackaged and redeployed, so that the App server registers the new methods and checks and grants/excludes the access privileges to the new/altered methods in EJB session beans.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here when injecting a Stateless SessionBean (TransactionAttribute.REQUIRES_NEW) into an other Stateless SessionBean. For me restarting the server solved it for me...

Just wanted to let you know ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I'm not using any kind of access control on the service but on one instance of glassfish everything worked fine, on another, I got this error but only on some methods. I added @PermitAll and redeployed the service and everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

On Glassfish 3.1.2 at least, sometimes a previous iteration of a bean that has changed will choke Glassfish at deployment. The app will run until it gets to whatever bit of code that should be called but can't be because the previously deployed class is still there. I think Glassfish might keep track of each and prevent the new code from calling the old code, but I haven't really been that keen to worry about it as the solution is simple enough:

Stop the server, go to the domain directory and delete all the files and sub-directories in the application directory. Then do the same in the generated and osgi-cache directories. Restart the server and rebuild/redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same Error but mine was caused from this:

```
<c:set var="speciesList" value="#{timberSaleController.distinctSaleSpecies}"   />
```

the function:

```
public List<Species> getDistinctSaleSpecies()
    {
        return ejbFacade.getDistinctSpeciesForAllSales();
    }
```

when i changed the set tag to this it worked:

```
<c:set var="speciesList" value="#{timberSaleController.getDistinctSaleSpecies()}"   />
```