# Mutliple Roles within Secured REST Endpoint Internal Server Error

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-rs

I have a RESTful webservice that I want to allow different roles on different endpoints. For example I have the following class with two method one for the admin role to access and one for the manager role to access. I'm using Glassfish and have setup the JDBCRealm, and I have created two users, one for each role.

```
@Stateless
@Path("testrole")
@DenyAll
public class TestRoleREST {

   @RolesAllowed("admin")
   @GET
   @Path("admin")
   @Produces("application/xml")
   public TestData getAdmin() {
      return new TestData("admin", 0);
   }

   @RolesAllowed("manager")
   @GET
   @Path("manager/{id}")
   @Produces("application/xml")
   public TestData getManager(@PathParam("id") Integer id){
      return new TestData("manager", id);
   }


   @XmlRootElement
   @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
   public static class TestData{
      private String roleName;
      private int number;

      private TestData(){
      }

      public TestData(String roleName, int number){
         this.roleName = roleName;
         this.number = number;
      }
   }
}
```

---

Using curl on the URI:testrole/manager/2 returns as expected some XML and the same is true on the URI:testrole/admin for the admin user. If I don't provide credentials I get an HTTP 401 Not Authorized which is expected.

```
curl -X GET -H "Accept:application/xml" -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -u manager:test http://localhost/server/rest/testrole/manager/2

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<testData>
   <roleName>manager</roleName>
   <number>2</number>
</testData>
```

However if I use curl on the URI:testrole/admin using the manager user then I get an HTTP 500 internal server error, which is due to `javax.ejb.AccessLocalException: Client not authorized for this invocation`.

```
curl -X GET -H "Accept:application/xml" -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -u manager:test http://localhost/server/rest/testrole/admin
```

---

Why doesn't the authenticated user just receive HTTP 401, 403 or some other normal error code? Is there a way to configure the application to return a preferred HTTP error code or have I missed some bit of configuration?

It seems a bit heavy handed to throw AccessLocalException which inherits from  RuntimeException just because an authenticated user attempted access an unauthorized URI.

This question ([JPA Glassfish Database Update Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582669/jpa-glassfish-database-update-issue)) seems to deal with the same exception and reason, but I don't understand how or even if it relates to my question. I have a working service when using the properly authenticated and authorized user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a partial solution to my question in an answer on another somewhat unrelated question ([JAX-RS — How to return JSON and HTTP status code together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687271/jax-rs-how-to-return-json-and-http-status-code-together)). The answer was to use an `javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper` to mask the internal server exception on the client side. This still causes a stack trace to be generated on the server, but at least the client isn't exposed to the HTTP 500 code.

The code for the mapper is simple enough and it allows me to customize the response when dealing with AccessLocalException.

```
@Provider
public class ApplicationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<AccessLocalException> {

   @Override
   public Response toResponse(AccessLocalException exception) {
      return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
   }
}
```

As I said at the beginning this is a partial answer because I still think the server shouldn't generate an exception for an authenticated user accessing an unauthorized endpoint, but perhaps that's what the original developers intended. If there is another piece to the puzzle in terms of configuring the roles on the REST endpoints so as not to generate an AccessLocalException, please share. In the mean time I can live with this ExceptionMapper solution.